the largest eigenvalue of compound matrix $A^{(k)}$
On the textbook I see a collary:
Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ complex positive semidefinite square matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1(A)\geq ...\geq \lambda_n(A)$.Then the largest eigenvalue of $A^{(k)}$ is the product of the first $k$ largest eigenvalues of $A$; that is,
$$
\lambda_\max(A^{(k)})=\prod_{i=1}^k\lambda_i(A)
$$
Here $A^{(k)}$ means the $k$th compound matrix of $A$.
On the text the author says it is a corollary of the following theorem:
Let $A$ be an $m×p$ matrix and $B$ be a $p×n$ matrix.
If $k$ is a positive integer, $k ≤ \min\{m,p,n\}$, then $(AB)^{(k)} = A^{(k)} B^{(k)}$ .
How can I get the collary from the theorem?

What’s the question here?

Oh,I forget it..thanks

@Pranay I haven't learnt that.

We can write $A = PDP^{-1}$, where $D=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ and $P$ is a unitary matrix. Then using the theorem for product of matrices, we get
$$
(P^{(k)})^{-1} = (P^{-1})^{(k)},\qquad A^{(k)}= P^{(k)} D^{(k)} (P^{(k)})^{-1}.
$$
Since $D$ is diagonal, the only nonzero entries of $D^{(k)}$ are the principal $k$-minors, which means $D^{(k)}$ is diagonal and hence its diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A^{(k)}$. Moreover, the principal $k$-minors are simply products of $k$ distinct $\lambda_i$’s. The largest of these is the product of $k$ largest eigenvalues of $A$, which gives you the corollary.
